# Thousands separator in sql with dot in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to cast numeric type let say `30000` into string type with dot as thousand separator `30.000`.

I tried to use

```
SELECT FORMAT("%'.0f", CAST(30000 as NUMERIC))
```

But the result is `30,000` not `30.000`

Comment: 30,000 is correct for many countries. What locale is your browser/operating system set to?

Comment: yes I know, but in my country (Indonesia) it's reversed lol @Evert
can we manually convert it within bigquey?

Comment: Could you do a `REPLACE` after to just convert the `,` to `.`?

Comment: Could you pass me the whole syntax? I'm not following @Evert

Comment: Something like: `SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT("%'.0f", CAST(30000 as NUMERIC)), ',', '.'))` ?

Comment: Brilliant! @Evert please write your answer not in comment

Comment: Sure, sounds good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just replace the `,` with `.` after formatting:

```sql
SELECT 
  REPLACE(
    FORMAT("%'.0f", CAST(30000 as NUMERIC)),
    ',',
    '.'
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

Most likely in some case you will need not just replace `,` with `.` but also replace `.` to `,` to format numbers with decimals
In such cases consider below example

```
SELECT 
  TRANSLATE(
    FORMAT("%'.2f", CAST(30000.12 as NUMERIC)),
    ',.',
    '.,'
  )
```

with output

```
30.000,12
```